# ansible when condition fails

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

the following when condition fails with parsing error.

```
  - name: some task
    debug:
      msg: "{{ansible_host}}"
    when: "({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_xyz in group_names) or ({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_efg in group_names)"
```

I basically want this task to run if a certain variable is equal to foo and the host belongs to a few certain groups in inventory

The error message

```
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_xyz in group_names) or ({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_efg in group_names)' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_xyz in group_names) or ({{somevariable}} == 'foo' and ABC_{{bar}}_efg in group_names)): 'foo' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/playbooks/playbook.yml': line 23, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: some task\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `{{` `}}` with the `when` condition. see [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when) official documentation. Means, your expression should look like below:

```
when: "(somevariable == 'foo' and 'ABC_' + bar + '_xyz' in group_names) or (somevariable == 'foo' and 'ABC_' + bar + '_efg' in group_names)"
```